# How to disable the message option in the Native Call Screen?

Tags: ios, ios10, callkit

There is a message option in the native call screen before you answer the call. See screen shot below:

[image: Screen Shot]

Currently it uses the native messaging app to send the message, which is not desirable for my feature.

Is there a way to disable it from the native call screen?
A better solution would be to delegate the messaging feature to my app, is there any way to do that?

Comment: Are you able to hide the  Message/Remind Me buttons, if yes please let me know how do that..

Comment: how To Show the message icon??/ @david

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to disable this button in the native incoming call UI or change it to use your app instead.

If you would like the ability to disable it or change it to use your VoIP app's own messaging service, I recommend submitting this as an enhancement request on Apple's bug reporting website at https://bugreport.apple.com